# Error installing nodejs ari-client library

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, asterisk

I am trying to install **ari-client**,using this command:

```
sudo npm install ari-client
```

Here is the error I get:

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ari-client
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ari-client
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/swagger-client/2.0.26
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ws/0.4.31
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.6.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
npm http 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid/-/node-uuid-1.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! Error: 400 Bad Request
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/fetch.js:57:12)
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at fs.js:1601:14
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/bzegeju/npm-debug.log npm

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-26-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ari-client"
npm ERR! cwd /home/bzegeju
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ws/0.4.31
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.6.0
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/swagger-client/2.0.26
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bzegeju/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any help on the error or how I can manually install the library?

Answer (score 0):

For Manual installation:

```
1.Go to npm site search for "ari-client".

 2.Click the given "github" link , from there you can download as ZIP file.

 3.Extract it and use in your project
```